# Relationship between $ [0,1]^{n} $ and $ R^{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From the book of Munkres:

**Theorem 34.1 (Urysohn metrization theorem)** Every regular space $ X $ with a countable basis is metrizable.

Idea of the proof:

- The hypothesis implies that there exists a countable collection of continuous functions $ f_{n}: X \rightarrow [0,1] $ having the property that given any point $ x_{0} \in X $ and any neighborhood $ U $ of $ x_{0} $, there exists an index $ N $ such that $ f_{N}(x_{0}) > 0$ and $ f_{N}(x) = 0 $ for all $ x \in X \setminus U $.
- Define $ F: X \rightarrow R^{w} $ as $ F(x) = (f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x),\cdot\cdot\cdot)$.
- $ F $ is an embedding (that is, $ F: X \rightarrow F(X) = [0, 1]^{w} \subset R^{w}$ is a homeomorphism).
- Now $ R^{w} $ is metrizable, so the subspace $ [0,1]^{w} $ is metrizable and hence $ X $ is metrizable.

In the development of the proof of this theorem, I had the doubt of the relationship between $ [0,1] $ and $ R $ and between $ [0,1]^{n} $ and $ R^{n} $. That is,

$ [0,1]^{n} $ is homeomorphic to $ R^{n} $?

Comment: No. $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. One is compact, the other is not.  Nevertheless $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Maybe (0,1), otherwise one is compact and the other is not. In case of open interval, yes. And generally if f: X \simeq Y is an isomorphism you can get an isomorphism X^n \simeq Y^n by setting g(x_1,..,x_n) = (f(x_1), .. , f(x_n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not since it is compact and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not. For the same reason $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.